# Set a String of URLs to an URI object?

Tags: android

How to set the String URL as the data for the Intent as a Uri object?

Where am I going wrong?

```
protected String[] mUrls = { "http://www.teamtreehouse.com", "http://developer.android.com", "http://www.github.com" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUrls);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse(mUrls));
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont pass the array of urls. You need the select the one on each list item therefore change the code to:

```
protected String[] mUrls = { "http://www.teamtreehouse.com", "http://developer.android.com", "http://www.github.com" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUrls);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse(mUrls[position]));
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse only one `String` with method `Uri.parse(String uriString)`, so you can't put there the String array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(mUrls));
```

This looks quite wrong. `mUrls` is an array of Strings and you're parsing it into one `Uri`, that won't work. 
You'll have to parse every String from the Array into different Uris.

Atention: this is not real working code but a pseudo-code like example:

```
intent.setData(mUrls);
```

And where you receive the data:

```
for (String s : mUrls){

Uri u = Uri.parse(s); 

}
```